# Return Dynamic data from database to Chart in php codeignter

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter

Please I am trying to return a dynamic data from my database to a graph chart in php CodeIgniter but I got the following result[image]

When I try to console log the return json data it out the following:

```
[{"user_username":"seunex","totupl":"2"},{"user_username":"zubgan","totupl":"1"},{"user_username":"zubdev","totupl":"0"}]
```

Here is my code:

**Controller:**

```js
public function chart_data() {
    $tops = $this->Item_model->getTopItemsAuthor();

    if ($tops) {
        $data = array();
        foreach($tops as $top){ 
            $data[] = $top;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode ($data);
}
```

**Model**

```js
// Get top item uploader
fun getTopItemsAuthor(): function {
    { `$this` -> { db -> select('u.user_username,COUNT(t.item_id) AS totupl') } }
    { `$this` -> { db -> from('zd_users u') } }
    { `$this` -> { db -> join('zd_items t', 't.item_user_id = u.user_id', 'left') } }
    { `$this` -> { db -> group_by('u.user_id') } }
    { `$this` -> { db -> order_by('totupl', 'DESC') } }
    `$query` = { `$this` -> { db -> get() } }
    if ({ `$query` -> num_rows() > 0 }) {
        return { `$query` -> result_array() }
    } else {
        return FALSE
    }
}
```

**Javascript**

```js
function (data ) {
    console.log(data);
    var name = [];
    var items = [];

    for (var i in data) {
        name.push(data[i].user_username);
        items.push(data[i].totupl);
    }

    var chartdata = {
        labels: name,
        datasets: [
            { label: 'Author Item',
              backgroundColor: '#49e2ff',
              borderColor: '#46d5f1',
              hoverBackgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
              hoverBorderColor: '#666666',
              data: items
            }
        ]
    };

    var graphTarget = $("#graphCanvas");

    var barGraph = new Chart (graphTarget, { type: 'bar', data: chartdata });
});
```

Comment: what about the var name? did you check it on console?

Comment: Yes it return in json form in console as.     [{"user_username":"seunex","totupl":"2"},{"user_username":"zubgan","totupl":"1"},{"user_username":"zubdev","totupl":"0"}]

Comment: try with these statements instead in js

`data[i]["user_username"]`
`data[i]["totupl"]`

Comment: which chart library do you use ?

Comment: please try to rename your variable "name"
https://roan-blinker.glitch.me/

Comment: Am using chartjs library

Comment: @mike watawski please help me I could not understand what to rename please

Comment: please check source code https://roan-blinker.glitch.me/

Comment: Fix now I notice the object are return in string so I have to parse it to json to make it and object.